# Reading .txt file data and inserting it into struct array

Tags: c, scanf, fopen

I've been trying to read a .txt file and insert the data into a struct array, but I've encountered an issue, where the data gets read multiple times at the end.

Source file:

```
123479 Drozd 4
213872 Jas 5
132763 Tom 6
```

Expected results:

```
Drozd 4
Jas 5
Tom 6
```

What I get:

```
Drozd 4
Jas 5
Tom 6
Tom 6
Tom 6
```

My code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 5 // max array size

typedef struct 
{
    char name[80];
    int grade;
}para;

void read( FILE *file,  para tab[], int m) {
    char path[80];
    printf("Enter the file path: ");
    scanf_s("%s", path, 80);
    file= fopen(path, "r");

    if (path== NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            int index;
            char name[80];
            int grade;
            fscanf(plik, "%d %80s %d", &index, name, &grade);
            strcpy(tab[i].name, name);
            tab[i].grade= grade;
        }
    }
    if (file!=NULL)
    {
        fclose(file);
    }
}

void print_array(para tab[], int m){
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", tab[i].name, tab[i].grade);
    }
    
}


int main() {
    FILE* file;
    para tab[5];
    read(&file, tab, MAX);
    print_array(tab, MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

The reason for ignoring 'index' integer at the beginning of each row is that the task requires me only to enter a student's name and grade into the array.

Comment: OT: `if (path== NULL)` this test is useless, because `path` can never be NULL. Did you mean `if (file == NULL)`? And `FILE *file` as first parameter of `read` is usless. Declare it simply as local variable in `read`.

Comment: You're trying to read 5 lines from an input file with 3, stop reading when `fscanf()` returns 0 and return that value to the caller to use it in `print_array()`.

Comment: Also: be consistent: you're using `5` and `MAX` which is also 5. This is dangerous practice....

Comment: I get compiler errors and warnings when I try to compile your program. I guess the code in the question is different from what you ran on your system. Enable all warnings and fix them. See https://airbus-seclab.github.io/c-compiler-security/